# Firefox: How to block Javascript Alert Box

Tags: javascript, firefox

Receive an 'alert box' (not a separate pop up), where I have to click 'OK' every time I access a site

Is there any way in Firefox to disable/block it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVSNq.png

Comment: Disable javascript in your browser (not recommended). Firefox also has the feature "Do not show prompt messages again", but only works on the same page. This setting will be resetted if you visit another page.

Comment: Using NoScript: I Disable javascript, This works, but then I loose other functionality on the page

Firefox never gave me the option: "Do not show prompt messages again"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to reload the page you can add execute:

`window.alert = function() {};`

In the developer console. This will overwrite the `alert` function with an empty function.